# How to prepare data for ListVectorPlot[]?

Tags: plotting

I was trying to plot a few velocity vectors measured at given points. However I am unable to do this with `ListVectorPlot[]` function. I get error each time I try to use it (it says: `VisualizationCoreListVectorPlot::vfldata: {{{1,1},{2,2}}}` is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets.). Finally I succeeded using `Arrow[]` graphics entity, but I'd rather use `ListVectorPlot[]` function.

Lets say I have three

```
points={{1,1},{2,1},{3,1}}
```

and 2D vectors measured in that points:

```
vec={{1,0},{0.7,0.1},{1,-0.1}}
```

How to prepare data to plot this using ListVectorPlot to get such an image:

[image: Arrows obrained by the following code:]

Code used to plot arrows:

```
ar = {
  Graphics[Arrow[{{1, 1}, {1 + 1, 1 + 0}}]], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{{2, 1}, {2 + 0.7, 1 + 0.1}}]], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{{3, 1}, {3 + 1, 1 - 0.1}}]]
}; 
Show[ar]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me explain the error message first. You assumed that you can give a list of points and vectors and `ListVectorPlot` draws exactly those vectors. This is not the case. If you give `ListVectorPlot` 4 vectors on the corner of the unit-square, it will do the following:

```
ListVectorPlot[{
  {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
  {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}},
  {{1, 1}, {-1, -1}}, 
  {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See that it interpolates all values in between? And here is the problem with your dataset. All your vectors lie on a line which makes it impossible to create a 2d-plot.

Therefore, are you sure you want to use `ListVectorPlot`? What you try can be achieved in one line of code (no matter how many points and vectors you have!)

```
Graphics[Arrow[{#1, #1 + #2}] & @@@ Transpose[{points, vec}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot for an explanation. However I can never understand, why such things like Matlab or Mathematica have no functions for plotting vector or scalar fields on FEM or other domains.

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from the fact that all your points **lie along a line**, while [**documentation states**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListVectorPlot.html) "ListVectorPlot by default interpolates the data given, and plots vectors for the vector field at a regular grid of positions." I think algorithm cannot produce interpolated 2D field based on 1D data. Let's deviate your data slightly from horizontal line by off-setting vertical coordinate of middle point by 10% up:

```
points = {{1, 1}, {2, 1 + 0.1}, {3, 1}};
vec = {{1, 0}, {0.7, 0.1}, {1, -0.1}};
```

Now you can easily produce interpolated vector field:

```
ListVectorPlot[Transpose[{points, vec}], 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[points]}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]
```

[image]

If you wish to see only your **given** vectors, you need to realize: (1) the vector field by default is generated by passing through the given points, not starting at them, (2) the vector length and arrowhead scales need to be chosen wisely:

```
ListVectorPlot[Transpose[{points, vec}], 
 VectorPoints -> All, 
 VectorScale -> {1, Scaled[.2]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[points]}]
```

[image]