# Plotting a vector field

Tags: plotting

Can I somehow plot a vector field and the scattered data point associated with each and every vector? Also, is there any way to prevent *Mathematica* from interpolting the vector field?

I am trying to plot this data as a vector field. The data is from a .dat file that includes the following four columns: x-coord, y-coord, vecx, vecy.

http://wikisend.com/download/386548/testBC.dat

I managed to plot the following with Tecplot

[image]

I am trying to remake this plot in Mathematica

```
testBC = Import["C:\\...testBC.dat", "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
testBCx = testBC[[All, 1]];
testBCy = testBC[[All, 2]];
ux = testBC[[All, 3]];
uy = testBC[[All, 4]];
u = Transpose[{ux, uy}];
testbdry = Transpose[{testBCx, testBCy}];
ListVectorPlot[Transpose[{testbdry, u}], PlotRange -> Full, 
VectorPoints -> 10, VectorScale -> {0.1, 0.2}]
```

Results in the following

[image]

*Mathematica* interpolates the inside of the airfoil.

How can I remake the plot from Tecplot, i.e., how can I show the scatter plot of x, y, and the vectors pointing away from every point. Also, I want *Mathematica* to plot all the vectors as in Tecplot, not to only sample and interpolate.

Comment: See also [How to prepare data for ListVectorPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16404/245)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saved the data on my desktop and imported it.  To my surprise `ListVectorPlot` crashed my kernel.

```
orgData = Import["C:\\Users\\stelzer\\Desktop\\testBC.txt", "Data"];

Graphics[{Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{#1, #2}, {#1, #2} + 0.03 {#3, #4}}] & @@@ 
   orgData}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"v1", "v2"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for the option "VectorPoints -> All"; I *think* this achieves both your goals (one vector per coordinate and no interpolation):

```
testBC = Import["~/Downloads/testBC.dat", "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
testBCx = testBC[[All, 1]];
testBCy = testBC[[All, 2]];
ux = testBC[[All, 3]];
uy = testBC[[All, 4]];
u = Transpose[{ux, uy}];
testbdry = Transpose[{testBCx, testBCy}];
ListVectorPlot[Transpose[{testbdry, u}], 
    PlotRange -> Full, 
    VectorPoints -> All, 
    VectorStyle -> Automatic,
    AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
    VectorScale -> {0.1, 0.2}]
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

Note that I also changed the AspectRatio to approximate your initial plot image above.

Comment: @ernst-stelzer FYI: ListVectorPlot did not crash my kernel in v9.0.1 (Mac OS X 10.8.2)