# Problem with ListVectorPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a vector plot (3D or 2D) of the following list of 3 vectors. I simply failed to comprehend why I keep getting an error. Neither `ListVectorPlot3D` nor `ListvectorPlot` works.

```
Table[P2[[All, m, n]], {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}];
Dimensions[%]
ListVectorPlot3D[Table[P2[[All, m, n]], {m, 1, 5}, {n, 1, 5}]]

(* {5, 5, 3} *)
```

> `ListVectorPlot3D::vfldata:` "{{{-0.686557,-0.686557,0},{-0.670429,-0.705715,0},{-0.652753,-0.725281,0},{-0.633417,-0.745197,0},{-0.612312,-0.76539,0}},<<3>>,{{-0.76539,-0.612312,0},<<3>>,{-0.699795,-0.699795,0}}} is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets."

Comment: What is `P2`? It will help to diagnose the problem if we know what its values are.

Comment: Sorry, I should be much more informative. I have an array of 3-vectors on a 41x41 array (denoting the xy plane), creating a {3,41,41} matrix. I need to create a 3d (xyz) map of these vectors. I presume I need ListVector3D. But how do I covert my {3,41,41} to the requisite form?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the first form of `ListVectorPlot3D` then your `Dimensions` should be `{k,m,n,3}` - a 3D array of 3D vectors.
If you want the second form, then your dimensions should look `{...,2,3}` - a nD array of pairs of 3D vectors. Your `{5,5,3}` doesn't match any of these.

```
d1 = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 4}]; (* first form *)
d2 = Table[{{i, j, k}, {i, j, k}}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 4}]; (* second form *)
d3 = Flatten[d2, 2]; (* second form *)
Dimensions /@ {d1, d2, d3}
(* {{2, 3, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 2, 3}, {24, 2, 3}} *)
Row[ ListVectorPlot3D /@ {d1, d2, d3}]
```

Also you should decide what you are visualizing a 3D field (with `ListVectorPlot3D`) or a 2D field (with `ListVectorPlot`).

Since all your points are effectively in one plane you will face the problem mentioned
[here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16404/how-to-prepare-data-for-listvectorplot). `ListVectorPlot3D` will try to interpolate and fail. You can try to draw a lot of `Arrow`s instead:

```
arrows = Table[
   Arrow[{{i, j, 0}, {i, j, i + j}}], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 1, 10}];
Graphics3D@arrows
```

Comment: Sorry, I should be much more informative. I have an array of 3-vectors on a 41x41 array (denoting the xy plane), creating a {3,41,41} matrix. I need to create a 3d (xyz) map of these vectors. I presume I need ListVector3D. But how do I covert my {3,41,41} to the requisite form?

Comment: @AnshumanPal, I edited the answer.