# Plot a 3D vector field from a file

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, vector

I have a data file with six columns {x,y,z} and {ux,uy,uz} respectively, and I would like to plot the 3D vector field. 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/udoa61hu0m6itrc/campo.txt

I'm trying to do this,

```
te = Import["C:\\Users\\oliver\\Documents\\campo.txt", 
            "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
x = te[[All, 1]];
y = te[[All, 2]];
z = te[[All, 3]];
ux = te[[All, 4]];
vy = te[[All, 5]];
wz = te[[All, 6]];
point = Transpose[{x, y, z}];
vel = Transpose[{ux, vy, wz}];

ListVectorPlot3D[Transpose[{point, vel}], PlotRange -> Full,VectorPoints -> All]
```

The vector field must be as this picture, http://www.mediafire.com/download/9ddgux4ralx712k/1.jpg
[image]

Comment: Try this and tell me why I do not see similarity: `X = te[[;; 180, ;; 3]];
V = te[[;; 180, 4 ;; 6]];
Graphics3D[{Arrowheads@0.01, Arrow@Transpose[{X, X + V}], Red, Point@X}]`

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like the option `VectorPoints -> All` doesn't behave as described in the documentation of `ListVectorPlot3D` (2nd bullet of the Details and Options section).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries did You get any plot with `ListVectorPlot3D` with whatever options? I've failed to create any with {{X,V}...} data type.

Comment: @Kuba, I did that you said me and i get a plot with one disc, but the picture that i put , is of a set of disks, basically are circumferences displaced in z.

Comment: @Oli Yes I know, just delete `180` and leave `X = te[[;; , ;; 3]]; V = te[[;; , 4 ;; 6]]`. It definitely is that data set but I can not see those "X" features...

Comment: @Kuba, I'm new in Mathematica and i don't understad well, but i delete 180 and i get an error.

Comment: @Kuba, Which features do you mean?, the big arrows?.

Comment: @Kuba No. Try `ListVectorPlot3D[{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}}, 
 VectorPoints -> All]` and then change `{1, 1, 1}` to `{1, 1, 0}`. Weird. I'd say a bug or incorrect documentation.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Indeed. I have tried different things but no avail.

Comment: @Kuba Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27921/problem-with-listvectorplot3d

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries so it seems `ListVectorPlot3D` is simply not a proper tool for this. :)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries we should delete our discussion and leave here [halirutan's remark about `ListVectorPlot`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16405/5478) :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Almost, because OP wanted to recreate linked image. And just plotting the data vectors will not do that. (`Normalize` etc. included)

Comment: @Kuba If you think the rather too-localized (IMO) objective is to make the same picture, other than `Import["http:...1.jpg"]` ;), then perhaps.  But I would ask about that, since the vector field in the file is not the same as the vector field shown in the picture, even if the vector field were to be rescaled in a nonuniform way (unmentioned in the question).  (Consider the vertical components.)

Answer (score 1):

```
te = Import["campo.txt", "Table", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True];
X = te[[;; , ;; 3]];
V = te[[;; , 4 ;; 6]];

Graphics3D[{Arrowheads@.005, Arrow@Transpose[{X, X + .1 Normalize /@ V}]}, 
           BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 7}, PlotRange -> All, ViewPoint -> {1.5, 1.5, 0},  
           ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

On Your image there are couple of vectors thicker than the rest. Creating plot with variable thickness of arrows will result with heavy model so lets extract only the lognest and add them.

```
Histogram[Norm /@ (V)] (*I've checked this to set threshold to `1.7`*)
pos = Position[V, x_ /; Norm@x > 1.7, 1];

Graphics3D[{
            Arrowheads@.005, Arrow@Transpose[{X, X + .1 Normalize /@ V}][[ ;; ]],
            Red, Arrowheads@.02, Thick, 
            Arrow@Transpose[Extract[#, pos] & /@ {X, X + .3 Normalize /@ V}]  
            }, 
            BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 7}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 1200, 
            ViewPoint -> {0.444, 2.073, -0.036}, Boxed -> False,
            ViewVertical -> {-1.900, 2.937, -0.021}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Although not with ListVectorPlot...

Comment: I did this solution, but i get this error,  Arrow argument should be a list of coordinates, What is happening?.

Comment: @Oli is `te` what it should be? Try reset the kernel and reimport the data.

Comment: I did, but not working, i get the same error.

Comment: @Oli `Import["campo.txt"..` in Your case is different. Are You importing from right place. What error exactly are You getting?

Comment: These are the errors: Syntax::sntxf: ";;" cannot be followed by ",1;;3"., Syntax::tsntxi: ",1;;3" is incomplete; more input is needed., Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed., and Arrow argument should be a list of coordinates.

Comment: @Oli I can only advise You to recopy my code. It works for me :/.

Comment: @Kuba, Thanks a lot for you help, i'll copy again and i hope that work, i have a last question, when you assign values to X and V, this X = te[[;; , ;; 3]];, what is this?, why do you use this syntax ?.

Comment: @Oli I use this because I like it :) Take a look at `Span` in documentation.

Comment: @kuba, Ok, thanks, see you.