# ListVectorPlot3D invalid dataset

Tags: plotting, vector

I have generated a dataset which seems to fine according to the help page of Mathematica for a ListVectorPlot3D but, it says it is not a valid set. I have given the data set below, could someone please tell me what is wrong here? In each element the first list containing three elements is the position and the next list containing three elements is the vector components.

```
In[170]:= FullData1

Out[170]= {{{-0.027267, -0.0278571, 
   0.1}, {0.710454, -0.695403, -0.108031}}, {{-0.0380811, -0.00808106,
    0.1}, {0.206099, -0.971216, 0.119427}}, {{-0.0359774, 0.0154511, 
   0.1}, {-0.394081, -0.917603, 0.0520121}}, {{-0.020237, 0.0330941, 
   0.1}, {-0.844052, -0.516136, -0.145537}}, {{-0.000633865, 
   0.0392053, 0.1}, {-0.999843, -0.0161653, -0.00730729}}, {{0.020237,
    0.0330941, 0.1}, {-0.844052, 0.516136, 0.145537}}, {{0.0342857, 
   0.0190214, 0.1}, {-0.485118, 
   0.874415, -0.0077212}}, {{0.0379892, -0.00857143, 0.1}, {0.218605, 
   0.968876, -0.116149}}, {{0.0228341, -0.0314056, 0.1}, {0.800943, 
   0.582344, 0.139165}}, {{0.00214286, -0.0391452, 0.1}, {0.998203, 
   0.0546429, 0.0246024}}}

In[168]:= ListVectorPlot3D[FullData1]

During evaluation of In[168]:= Visualization`Core`ListVectorPlot3D::vfldata: {{{-0.027267,-0.0278571,0.1},{0.710454,-0.695403,-0.108031}},<<8>>,{{0.00214286,-0.0391452,0.1},{0.998203,0.0546429,0.0246024}}} is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets.
```

Comment: Did you check [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27928/1356)? "_If you use the first form of ListVectorPlot3D then your Dimensions should be {k,m,n,3} - a 3D array of 3D vectors_". Your `FullData1` has `{10, 2, 3}` for `Dimensions`.

Comment: I think you are looking for something a little simpler, namely `Arrow /@ FullData1 // Graphics3D`

Comment: @Öskå I tried to use the second form for which I think the dimensions of `{10,2,3}` are fine.

Comment: If you want to use `ListVectorPlot3D` you need an array with `{k,m,n,3}` as `Dimensions`. If you want to stick with your `{10,2,3}` you are free to use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27928/1356) or the [equivalent from gpap](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47899/listvectorplot3d-invalid-dataset#comment142117_47899).