# Trouble with ListVectorPlot3D

Tags: vector-calculus

I am trying to visualize a complex vector field. However, I seem to have difficulty with the usage of `ListVectorPlot3D`. The following example works in two dimension, but not in 3D.

I define three points and three vectors:

```
phasePRange = {{0., 1.}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}};
phaseBRatios = {1., 2.5, 2.5};

myps = 
  {{0.6317509602269538, 0., 0.}, 
   {0.6315222309581698, -0.49206031006953616, 0.8084147318366528}, 
   {0.6309571144534679, -0.3287921492246488, 1.4140959092626375}};

myvs = 
  {{-6.627612561711319*^-11, -0.5525297131274786, 0.8334932009988242}, 
   {-0.0005729018280423939, -0.39025963088261206, 0.9207046715895726}, 
   {-0.0005483923990602963, 0.884592445730268, 0.46636456149960553}};
```

and I can display them using the Arrow command:

```
Graphics3D[
  {{Black, PointSize[.03], Point[myps[[1]]]},
   {Black, PointSize[.03], Point[myps[[2]]]}, 
   {Black, PointSize[.03], Point[myps[[3]]]}, 
   {Thick,Arrowheads[0.03],
     {Blue, Arrow[{myps[[1]], myps[[1]] + myvs[[1]]}]}, 
     {Red, Arrow[{myps[[2]], myps[[2]] + myvs[[1]]}]}, 
     {Green, Arrow[{myps[[3]], myps[[3]] + myvs[[3]]}]}}},
  Axes -> True,
  Boxed -> True,
  BoxRatios -> phaseBRatios, 
  PlotRange -> phasePRange]
```

[image]

However, when I evaluate

```
myfield = Transpose[{myps, myvs}]
ListVectorPlot3D[myfield,
   VectorPoints -> All,
   VectorScale -> {1., Scaled[.1]}, 
   BoxRatios -> phaseBRatios, 
   AxesLabel -> {"ϵ","u","y"},
   PlotRange -> phasePRange]
```

I get an empty box with no arrows.

I woudl apprecaite any help to figure out my mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much for improving my post layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the data. `ListVectorPlot3D` is a variation of `VectorPlot3D` that attempts to interpolate the data you supply to reproduce the underlying function. If it can't interpolate, it will not draw anything or produce an error. The documentation says:

> ListVectorPlot3D by default interpolates the data given and plots vectors for the vector field at a regular 3D grid of positions.

Also, the format for `ListVectorPlot3D` comes in two flavors (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27928/44141)). You need to make sure you are either providing pairs of points/vectors sufficient for interpolation, or you are giving an array of vectors.

As a thought experiment, think about this in 2D. You need to provide at least 3 data points for the interpolation to work. So, if you want to have a field of straight vectors and you try to do it by simply doing

```
ListVectorPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}}]
```

it wouldn't work -- can't interpolate with two points. So, you need to add a third point, like this:

```
ListVectorPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{.5, .5}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}}]
```

The same is true about 3D. You have to provide enough data points so that they can be interpolated.

Read more about it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27921/problem-with-listvectorplot3d).

Comment: Thank you Stitch very much. Very helpful. This resolves my immediate issue. I wonder why it does not give an error? I tried the following test with different nu2 values. It works with all values nu2=>2. For nu2=1 it gives an error:

Comment: <br/> I tried the following test with different nu2 values. It works with all values nu2=>2. For nu2=1 it gives an error: <br/>"Visualization`Core`ListVectorPlot3D::vfldata: {{{{{1.,1.,1.},{1.,0.,0.5}}}}} is not a valid vector field dataset or a valid list of datasets."<br/><pre>wind2 = Table[{{i, j, z}, {i, -j, -z}}, {i, 1, nu2}, {j, 1, nu2}, {z, 
    1, nu2}]; <code><br/><pre>ListVectorPlot3D[wind2, VectorColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"]<code>

Comment: @I.Konuk When you have nu2=1, you have only one point -- the format is {{point},{vector}}, so there is nothing to plot. My understanding is that it doesn't produce an error when the structure of an array is consistent, but it can't interpolate.