# How to adjust or surpass the interpolation in ListVectorPlot and ListStreamPlot?

Tags: plotting, interpolation

How does Mathematica [interpolate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16404/how-to-prepare-data-for-listvectorplot) the field in `ListVectorPlot` and `ListStreamPlot`?

Is there away to adjust the interpolation algorithm or to surpass it?

I tried to changed `VectorPoints`, but it looks like Mathematica still interpolates the data:

```
ListVectorPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 
    1}, {-1, -1}}, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}}, VectorPoints -> 4]
ListStreamPlot[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {-1, 0}}, {{1, 
    1}, {-1, -1}}, {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}}, VectorPoints -> 4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought the option `VectorPoints -> All` gave the possibility to bypass any interpolation where you give explicitly the point and direction vector manually in the list.

```
ListVectorPlot[
 Table[{{x, y}, {RandomInteger[{-1, 1}], RandomInteger[{-1, 1}]}}, {x,
     1, 20}, {y, 1, 20}] /. {0, 0} -> {1, 1}, VectorPoints -> All]
```

[image: vector plot]