# Plot vectors read in from file

Tags: plotting, vector

From a file, I read in vectors and their origins. I construct a table from this which I want to plot in 3 dimensions. However, the `ListVectorPlot3D` only shows an empty box. What am I doing wrong? Here an example:

```
data = {{{0.014142139999989922, -0.014142139999989922, -0.25}, 
{0.23575464959, 
     0.23575464959, -0.94278284371}}, {{0.012548079999987749,
-0.01557729000001018, -0.24999081999999362}, {0.22429693407, 
     0.22429693407, -0.94835740664}}, {{0.01263210999999842,
-0.015493259999999509, -0.24999180999998316}, {0.22493433594, 
     0.22493433594, -0.94805542508}}, {{0.012716149999988602,
-0.015409220000009327, -0.24999275000004673}, {0.22557163945, 
     0.22557163945, -0.94775253677}}, {{0.012800199999986717,
-0.015325170000011212, -0.24999362000005476}, {0.22620884412, 
     0.22620884412, -0.94744874145}}};

ListVectorPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> None, 
 VectorPoints -> All]
```

Comment: Isn't `Graphics3D@Arrow@data` what you want? closely related: [16404](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16404/5478)

Comment: The dimensions of data do not match the requirements of ListVectorPlot3D. Please check the first documentation example in the page for ListVectorPlot3D

Comment: @Lotus The doc lists as a second syntax as data input exactly what I used, or do I misunderstand it?